# how can I change the datetimepicker value(when it is readonly)

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I'm trying to change the default value of a datetimepicker in my form in the formload event(I mean I don't want the datetimepicker's value to be 'now' when my app starts.I want it to be equal to some string value that my app should read from registry.)
so I tried this:

```
    datepicker.Value.Date = //some string value converted to datetime
```

but it gets me an error that the datepicker is readonly and cannot be assigned.
I can use the add method as my last solution.But I am hoping for a better one.
thanks in advance.best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Value.  Value.Date however has no setter.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // this works
     dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.MinDate;

     // this does not
     dateTimePicker1.Value.Date = // Value.Date has no setter
}
```

Comment: I just wanted my datetimepicker to pick and show the date.and I thought I need to set the date property itself.but your answer worked.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

DateTimePicker.Value.Date is readonly, instead use

```
DateTimePicker.Value = SomeDateTime
```